# finding a file using general location in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, file

I making a script in python3. this script takes an input file. depends on who is running the script every time the location of this input file is different but always would be in the same directory as the script is. so I want to give the location of the input file to the script but basically the script should find it. my input file always would have the same name (`infile.txt`). to do so, I am using this way in `python3`:

```
path = os.path.join(os.getcwd())
input = path/infile.txt
```

but it does not return anything. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Use         os.path.join(path,"infile.txt")        , os.path.join is done to find the good delimiter according to the os. The first os.path.join is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.getcwd() return the working directory which can be different to the directory where the script is. The working directory corresponds from where python is executed.

In order to know where is the scipt you should use

`

```
    import os

    input = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), infile.txt) 
    # and you should use os.path.join
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question properly;

You have python script (sample.py) and a input file (sample_input_file.txt) in a directory say; D:\stackoverflow\sample.y and D:\stackoverflow\sample_input_file.txt respectively.

```
import os
stackoverflow_dir = os.getcwd()
sample_txt_file_path = os.path.join(stackoverflow_dir, 'sample_input_file.txt')
print(sample_txt_file_path)
```

os.path.join() takes *args as second argument which must have been your file path to join.